# wpf listview virtualization not working in debug mode

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I Use virtualization to solve performance issue :

```xml
<ListView VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
```

I can see changes when running without debugging (rendering is much faster).
To test without debugging I try to approaches :

- debug -> Start Diagnostic Tools Without Debugging
- go to main project bin folder and double click exe file

However it has no effect in debug mode. Why ?

I'm running Win 7 with Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your app with either of the methods you mention simply runs the exe from a debug build. A debug build has various compiler optimizations switched off so that you can use the build for debugging.

However, when you run with a debugger attached to a debug build it will run more slowly than running the same build without a debugger attached - this is because the debugger hooks into the CLR and combines the executing instructions with the loaded symbol files for your application to enable your IDE to hit breakpoints.

If you want to see how your app will perform in the real world, create a 'Release' build rather than a 'Debug' build, then run that build instead (without attaching a debugger).